# Author.p12 file not found error when creating a a hello world application for Blackberry

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am  trying to create  a Hello world application  using HTML5  Using WebWorks SDK v2.0 Beta for Blackberry 10 os

I created the project and   I installed the blackberry  simulator but when I tried -Build and install  from the  GUI of WebWorks SDK v2.0 Beta , I am not able to  create the built nor  see any output is been generated in the simulator  of blackberry

Below is the warning  which i see in cmd window:[image]

If the problems is because of author.p12   file,I tried to search for  the author.p12 file    but I could not find in my system , from where  will  i get this  file and   how?I have the bbidtoken csk file in  C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Research In Motion

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't created the author.p12 yet :)

In the GUI, if you click on the **Certificates** menu item (on the left), you should be able to enter in the information to create your author.p12 file. From there, you can go ahead and build away!